# Jersey produce duplicate log messages

Tags: java, jersey

Does anyone know why Jersey log duplicate messages?

Duplicated messages:

```
Apr 18, 2012 9:24:22 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:

Apr 18, 2012 9:24:22 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:

Apr 18, 2012 9:24:22 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.

Apr 18, 2012 9:24:22 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9.1 09/14/2011 02:05 PM'
```

Does the duplicate log messages indicate that we have something duplicate in our code?

Thanks

Comment: which message is duplicated exactly

Comment: The question was edited with the exact duplicated messages, Thanks.

Comment: again I don't see any duplicate messages ..

Comment: All the above messages are logged twice during startup. I didn't wrote them twice, but they do appear twice. Just after those 4 messages are logged, another 4 messages which are exactly the same logged again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22872046/duplicate-calls-received-to-restful-web-service-method-with-jersey-in-weblogic