# Duplicate calls received to RestFul web service method with Jersey in weblogic

Tags: java, web-services, rest, client-server, duplicates

I have RestFul web service method developed using jersey-bundle(1.1.1,1.17.1) and deployed to weblogic server 10.3.4.0.

I get duplicate calls for some of the call when client made. I get my rest service getting called twice when it actually made one.

I have capture some of the network logs using wireshark and found that it happens whenever stats [RST, ACK] sent by the server. What could be the reason for server sending back [RST] for some of the calls from client?

Comment: I am affected too, but cannot find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this report: [JERSEY-2616](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2616). I will check Jersey version 2.13 if it still contains duplicate calls bug.